# How to force fail a test in C# with MSTest

Tags: c#, webdriver, mstest

I am trying to port some of my WebDriver tests from JAVA to C#. What I'm stuck on is the situation when the driver cannot find some element on the page, in JAVA I do :

```
if (second >= 10) fail("timeout - " + list);
```

so if something takes more than 10 seconds the test fails with the timeout message. 
I tried a similar approach in C# with

```
if (sec >= 10) Debug.Fail("timeout : " + vList);
```

but this actually did not fail the test, but gave me an option to do so with the exception message box. That was a no no, I need my automatic test to fail outright on its own. Then I tried

```
if (sec >= 10) Assert.Fail("timeout : " + vList);
```

but this is throwing an unhandled exception error. Should I enclose the Assert.Fail in try/catch block? Or should I use something completely different to fail the test?

I am using MSTest, as mentioned in the topic.

**EDIT**: The exact message is :

> AssertFailedException was unhandled by user code. Assert.Fail failed.
>   timeout : someField.

on

> Assert.Fail("timeout : " + vList);

Comment: The unhandled exception, where does it get thrown?

Comment: This is the expected behavior. All `Assert` methods are throwing an `AssertFailedException` if they fail so you can see that the test was failed. If you catch the exception the test will pass.

Comment: Hmm, ok. The problem is that the test throws the unhandled exception and pauses, with the unhandled exception message displayed. I would like it to fail all right but stop afterwards, reporting fail.

Comment: Perhaps because you are debugging your test. If you run it will fail and the error will be displayed in the `Test Results` window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're seeing that behaviour because you've got the debugger attached to the running test - `Assert.Fail` throws `AssertFailedException`, your debugger sees the exception and breaks - and you don't get test results.

On the Debug menu, go into Exceptions, find `AssertFailedException` (or create an entry for it if it's not there) and make sure break on throw is turned off for that exception type.

Alternatively, run your tests without the debugger attached.

Comment: DIdin't even know you can start with/without debugging. I added the exception to the exceptions list and that solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Handy hint. `Ctrl-R then T` runs tests without the debugger attached, `Ctrl-R then Ctrl-T` runs tests *with* the debugger attached.

Answer (score 1):

Assert.Fail should be what you want to "force" a failure.  Internally, it will throw an `AssertFailedException`.  Something else could be going on if this doesn't work...

a quick dotPeek shows this gets called:

```
internal static void HandleFail(string assertionName, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
  string str = string.Empty;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    str = parameters != null ? string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Assert.ReplaceNulls((object) message), parameters) : Assert.ReplaceNulls((object) message);
  if (Assert.AssertionFailure != null)
    Assert.AssertionFailure((object) null, EventArgs.Empty);
  throw new AssertFailedException(FrameworkMessages.AssertionFailed((object) assertionName, (object) str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use appropriate syntax for mstest

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsSecondsGreaterOrEqualThanTen()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(second >= 10);
}
```

Comment: He wants the opposite. `Assert.IsTrue(second < 10);` or `Assert.IsFalse(second >= 10);`